# SQL Report Builder: Column visibility quirk

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

Soooo...this is weird. I'm in the process of overhauling a report by swapping out the dataset. One of my parameters utilizes column visibility to isolate different views. Before my overhaul, it worked fine and I haven't messed with it or anything really (I was very careful about being able to just replace my dataset and still have everything work as before, this is the one exception).

Here is my report with a 'normal' view. The parameter options are Sales, Collected, and Both and are grouped by month, as you can see:
[image]

When I select either Collected or Sales individually (Collected in this example), it drops my October group and Grand Total columns:

[image]

Here's where it gets weird...if I click View Report again, I can see the data I want to see while it's loading, but it doesn't spit it out like it should.

[image]

There is more weird, however. I've discovered that if I change my date selection to not actually use September, then it works fine. (@Start and @End date variables: I can select @Start as August and @End as October, no problems. But if either @Start or @End actually specify September, that's where my problems occur)

[image]

In the SQL query, there is nothing special about September data that would cause an issue, but will post the code in case anyone wants to see to verify.

```
USE PDI_Warehouse_2049_01

DECLARE @Salesperson VARCHAR(30)
    ,@Start DATE
    ,@End DATE
    ,@SalesType VARCHAR(30)
    ,@Customer VARCHAR(30)

SET @Salesperson = 'all'
SET @SalesType = 'all' --Options are CFN, Bulk, or All
SET @Start = '9/1/2019'
SET @End = '9/7/2019'
SET @Customer = 'all'

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #temp

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp_collectedGM') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #temp_collectedGM;

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#getsalesperson') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #getsalesperson

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#CFN') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #CFN

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#CFN_Bulk') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #CFN_Bulk;

--------------------------------------
--GET CFN VALUES
--------------------------------------
----1.First query gets list of salespeople associated to customers
SELECT DISTINCT c.Cust_Alias
    ,s.SalesPerson_Name
INTO #getsalesperson
FROM PDICompany_2049_01..CP_Transactions cp(NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN PDICompany_2049_01..Customers c(NOLOCK) ON CPTrn_Cust_Key = Cust_Key
LEFT JOIN PDICompany_2049_01..Customer_Sales_Info csi(NOLOCK) ON csi.CustSls_Cust_Key = c.Cust_Key
    AND CustSls_Salesperson_Key IS NOT NULL
LEFT JOIN PDICompany_2049_01..SalesPersons s ON csi.CustSls_Salesperson_Key = s.SalesPerson_Key
WHERE cp.CPTrn_Tran_Type != 0


-----2.Second query captures CFN values joining with #getsalesperson to bring it all together
-----NOTE: The GP originates as Sales GP. As it is collected, it remains the same value for Sales GP but becomes Collected GP as well.
SELECT DISTINCT c.Cust_Alias
    ,'CFN' AS [Prod Type]
    ,gsp.SalesPerson_Name
    ,case
        when datepart(year, ch.Chg_Last_Rcpt_Date) between datepart(year, @Start) AND datepart(year, @End) then datepart(year, ch.Chg_Last_Rcpt_Date)
        when datepart(year, cp.CPTrn_Business_Date) between datepart(year, @Start) AND datepart(year, @End) then datepart(year, cp.CPTrn_Business_Date)
        end as 'year'
    ,case
        when datepart(month, ch.Chg_Last_Rcpt_Date) between datepart(month, @Start) AND datepart(month, @End) then datepart(month, ch.Chg_Last_Rcpt_Date) 
        when datepart(month, cp.CPTrn_Business_Date) between datepart(month, @Start) AND datepart(month, @End) then datepart(month, cp.CPTrn_Business_Date)
        end as 'month'
    ,sum(CPTrn_Units) 'Gallons'
    ,CASE 
        WHEN si.Site_ID BETWEEN '2000'
                AND '2003'
            THEN sum(cp.CPTrn_Pretax_Ext_Amt) - sum(CPTrn_Ext_Cost)
        WHEN si.Site_ID BETWEEN '2900'
                AND '2999'
            THEN sum(cp.CPTrn_Total_Ext_Amt) - sum(CPTrn_Ext_Cost)
        END AS 'GP'
    ,sum(cp.CPTrn_Total_Ext_Amt) 'Sales w/tax'
    ,p.Prod_ID
    ,ch.Chg_Ref_No
    ,CASE 
        WHEN (datepart(year, ch.Chg_Last_Rcpt_Date) BETWEEN datepart(year, @Start)
                AND datepart(year, @End)
            AND datepart(month, ch.Chg_Last_Rcpt_Date) BETWEEN datepart(month, @Start)
                AND datepart(month, @End) 
                    or datepart(year, cp.CPTrn_Business_Date) BETWEEN datepart(year, @Start)
                AND datepart(year, @End)
            AND datepart(month, cp.CPTrn_Business_Date) BETWEEN datepart(month, @Start)
                AND datepart(month, @End))
            AND Chg_Status = 1
            THEN '1' 
        WHEN datepart(year, cp.CPTrn_Business_Date) BETWEEN datepart(year, @Start)
                AND datepart(year, @End)
            AND datepart(month, cp.CPTrn_Business_Date) BETWEEN datepart(month, @Start)
                AND datepart(month, @End)
            --AND Chg_Status = 0
            THEN '0'
        END AS 'status'
    INTO #CFN
FROM PDICompany_2049_01..CP_Transactions cp(NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN PDICompany_2049_01..Customers c(NOLOCK) ON CPTrn_Cust_Key = Cust_Key
INNER JOIN PDICompany_2049_01..Products p(NOLOCK) ON cp.CPTrn_Prod_Key = Prod_Key
LEFT JOIN PDICompany_2049_01..CP_Billing_Details CPBD(NOLOCK) ON CPBd.CPBillDtl_CPTrn_Key = cp.CPTrn_Key
    AND CPTrn_Cust_Key = CPBD.CPBillDtl_Cust_Key
    AND CPBD.CPBillDtl_Rec_Type = 1
LEFT JOIN PDICompany_2049_01..Customer_Locations cl(NOLOCK) ON c.Cust_WhPrcNtc_Def_CustLoc_Key = cl.CustLoc_Key
    AND ((CustLoc_Type & 2) <> 0)
LEFT JOIN #getsalesperson gsp ON c.Cust_Alias = gsp.Cust_Alias
LEFT JOIN PDICompany_2049_01..Charges ch(NOLOCK) ON ch.Chg_Ref_No = cpbd.CPBillDtl_Invoice_No
LEFT JOIN PDICompany_2049_01..Sites si(NOLOCK) ON si.Site_Key = cp.CPTrn_Site_Key
WHERE cp.CPTrn_Tran_Type != 0
    AND CPBillDtl_Invoice_No IS NOT NULL
    AND Salesperson_Name = CASE 
        WHEN @Salesperson IN (Salesperson_Name)
            THEN @Salesperson
        WHEN @Salesperson = 'All'
            THEN Salesperson_Name
        END
    AND c.Cust_Alias = CASE 
        WHEN @Customer IN (c.Cust_Alias)
            THEN @Customer
        WHEN @Customer = 'All'
            THEN c.Cust_Alias
        END
    and  ((datepart(year, ch.Chg_Last_Rcpt_Date) BETWEEN datepart(year, @Start) AND datepart(year, @End)
            AND datepart(month, ch.Chg_Last_Rcpt_Date) BETWEEN datepart(month, @Start) AND datepart(month, @End))
    or (datepart(year, cp.CPTrn_Business_Date) BETWEEN datepart(year, @Start) AND datepart(year, @End)
            AND datepart(month, cp.CPTrn_Business_Date) BETWEEN datepart(month, @Start) AND datepart(month, @End)))
    and CPBillDtl_Invoice_No is not null
    and ch.Chg_Ref_No is not null
GROUP BY c.Cust_Alias
    ,gsp.SalesPerson_Name
    ,datepart(year, ch.Chg_Last_Rcpt_Date)
    ,datepart(month, ch.Chg_Last_Rcpt_Date)
    ,datepart(year, cp.CPTrn_Business_Date)
    ,datepart(month, cp.CPTrn_Business_Date)
    ,ch.Chg_Ref_No
    ,p.Prod_ID
    ,cp.CPTrn_Key
    ,CPTrn_Ext_Cost
    ,si.Site_ID
    ,ch.Chg_Status
ORDER BY ch.Chg_Ref_No

-------------------------------------------------------------------
----GET BULK VALUES
-------------------------------------------------------------------
SELECT cu.Customer_Alias
    ,'Bulk' AS 'Prod Type'
    ,sp.SalesPerson_Name
    ,case
        when datepart(year, ch.Chg_Last_Rcpt_Date) between datepart(year, @Start) AND datepart(year, @End) then datepart(year, ch.Chg_Last_Rcpt_Date)
        when datepart(year, ch.chg_invoice_date) between datepart(year, @Start) and datepart(year, @End) then datepart(year, ch.chg_invoice_date)
        end as 'year'
    ,case
        when datepart(month, ch.Chg_Last_Rcpt_Date) between datepart(month, @Start) and datepart(month, @End) then datepart(month, ch.Chg_Last_Rcpt_Date)
        when datepart(month, ch.chg_invoice_date) between datepart(month, @Start) and datepart(month, @End) then datepart(month, ch.chg_invoice_date)
        end as 'month'
    ,CASE 
        WHEN p.Report_Group_Desc IN (
                'diesel'
                ,'gasoline'
                ,'aviation'
                ,'def'
                ,'kerosene'
                ,'propane'
                )
            OR p.Product_Id IN (
                'WEXALTERNATIVE'
                ,'WEXDEF'
                ,'WEXDSL'
                ,'WEXGAS'
                )
            OR p.Product_Id = CASE 
                WHEN cu.Customer_Alias = 'ONCOR ELECTRIC - WEX'
                    THEN 'WEXPURCHASES'
                WHEN cu.Customer_Alias = 'ONCOR ELECTRIC - WEX'
                    THEN 'WEXREBATE'
                END
            THEN sum(isnull(sales_qty, 0))
        ELSE 0
        END AS 'total gallons'
    ,sum(isnull(Ext_Retail_Base, 0) + isnull(Ext_Retail_Freight, 0)) - sum(isnull(Ext_Cost_Base, 0) + isnull(Ext_Cost_Freight, 0)) 'Sales GM'
    ,sum(isnull(Ext_Retail_Base, 0) + isnull(Ext_Retail_Freight, 0)) 'Sales'
    ,p.Product_Id
    ,fwsf.Invoice_Number
    ,CASE 
        WHEN (datepart(year, ch.Chg_Last_Rcpt_Date) BETWEEN datepart(year, @Start)
                AND datepart(year, @End)
            AND datepart(month, ch.Chg_Last_Rcpt_Date) BETWEEN datepart(month, @Start)
                AND datepart(month, @End)
                    or 
                datepart(year, ch.Chg_Invoice_Date) BETWEEN datepart(year, @Start)
                AND datepart(year, @End)
            AND datepart(month, ch.Chg_Invoice_Date) BETWEEN datepart(month, @Start)
                AND datepart(month, @End))
            AND Chg_Status = 1
            THEN '1'
        WHEN datepart(year, ch.Chg_Invoice_Date) BETWEEN datepart(year, @Start)
                AND datepart(year, @End)
            AND datepart(month, ch.Chg_Invoice_Date) BETWEEN datepart(month, @Start)
                AND datepart(month, @End)
            --AND Chg_Status = 0
            THEN '0'
        END AS 'status'
    INTO #temp
FROM PDI_Warehouse_2049_01.dbo.Fuel_Wholesale_Sales_Fact fwsf
JOIN PDI_Warehouse_2049_01.dbo.calendar c ON fwsf.Calendar_key = c.calendar_key
JOIN Salesperson sp ON sp.SalesPerson_Key = fwsf.Salesperson_Key
JOIN Customer cu ON fwsf.Customer_Key = cu.Customer_Key
JOIN PDI_Warehouse_2049_01..Petroleum_Product p ON p.Petroleum_Product_Key = fwsf.Petroleum_Product_Key
JOIN PDICompany_2049_01..Charges ch ON ch.Chg_Ref_No = fwsf.Invoice_Number
WHERE sp.Salesperson_Name = CASE 
        WHEN @Salesperson IN (Salesperson_Name)
            THEN @Salesperson
        WHEN @Salesperson = 'All'
            THEN Salesperson_Name
        END
    AND ((datepart(year, ch.Chg_Last_Rcpt_Date) BETWEEN datepart(year, @Start) AND datepart(year, @End)
            and datepart(month, ch.Chg_Last_Rcpt_Date) BETWEEN datepart(month, @Start) AND datepart(month, @End))
            or 
        (datepart(year, ch.Chg_Invoice_Date) BETWEEN datepart(year, @Start) AND datepart(year, @End)
            AND datepart(month, ch.Chg_Invoice_Date) BETWEEN datepart(month, @Start) AND datepart(month, @End)))
    and Invoice_Number is not null  
    --  AND isnull(fwsf.sales_qty, 0) != 0
    AND cu.Customer_Alias = CASE 
        WHEN @Customer IN (cu.Customer_Alias)
            THEN @Customer
        WHEN @Customer = 'All'
            THEN cu.Customer_Alias
        END
GROUP BY sp.SalesPerson_Name
    ,datepart(year, ch.Chg_Last_Rcpt_Date)
    ,datepart(month, ch.Chg_Last_Rcpt_Date)
    ,datepart(year, ch.chg_invoice_date)
    ,datepart(month, ch.chg_invoice_date)
    ,p.Report_Group_Desc
    ,p.Product_Id
    ,Invoice_Number
    ,cu.Customer_Alias
    ,p.Product_Id
    ,ch.Chg_Status
HAVING sum(isnull(sales_qty, 0)) != 0

---------------------------------------
----------final result--
-----------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE #CFN_Bulk (
    Customer_Alias VARCHAR(50)
    ,[Prod Type] VARCHAR(5)
    ,Salesperson_Name VARCHAR(50)
    ,year int
    ,month int
    ,[total gallons] FLOAT
    ,[Sales GM] FLOAT
    ,Sales FLOAT
    ,[Product_Id] VARCHAR(30)
    ,Invoice_Number VARCHAR(30)
    ,Chg_Status BIT
    );

INSERT INTO #CFN_Bulk
SELECT *
FROM #temp t

UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM #CFN c;

SELECT Customer_Alias
    ,[Prod Type] 'Prod_Type'
    ,Salesperson_Name
    ,year
    ,month
    ,CASE 
        WHEN Chg_Status = 1
            THEN sum([total gallons])
        END AS 'Collected_gallons'
    ,CASE 
        WHEN Chg_Status = 0
            OR Chg_Status = 1
            THEN sum([total gallons])
        END AS 'Sold_gallons'
    ,Sales
    ,[Product_Id]
    ,Invoice_Number
    ,Chg_Status
    ,CASE 
        WHEN Chg_Status = 1
            THEN sum([Sales GM])
        END AS 'Collected_GM'
    ,CASE 
        WHEN Chg_Status = 0
            OR Chg_Status = 1
            THEN sum([Sales GM])
        END AS 'Sales_GM'
FROM #CFN_Bulk
WHERE [Prod Type] = CASE 
        WHEN @SalesType = 'CFN'
            THEN 'CFN'
        WHEN @SalesType = 'bulk'
            THEN 'Bulk'
        WHEN @SalesType = 'All'
            THEN [Prod Type]
        END
    AND Salesperson_Name = CASE 
        WHEN @Salesperson IN (Salesperson_Name)
            THEN @Salesperson
        WHEN @Salesperson = 'All'
            THEN Salesperson_Name
        END
    AND Customer_Alias = CASE 
        WHEN @Customer IN (Customer_Alias)
            THEN @Customer
        WHEN @Customer = 'All'
            THEN Customer_Alias
        END
    AND Salesperson_Name != 'undefined'
GROUP BY Customer_Alias
    ,[Prod Type]
    ,Salesperson_Name
    ,year
    ,month
    ,[total gallons]
    ,Sales
    ,[Product_Id]
    ,Invoice_Number
    ,Chg_Status
ORDER BY Invoice_Number
```

---

Any ideas as to what might be causing this would be greatly appreciated. I'm really quite perplexed by this.

---

**UPDATE 1:** The column visibility expressions are very simple. Here's an example of one for the Collected column (as the expression is predetermined for 
a Hidden view):

`=Parameters!View2.Value = "Sales"`

So when I select Sales from my drop-down, it hides this Collected column. I don't think there can be any issue with any of my logic/expressions, because as noted, it worked perfectly with my last dataset and with this new dataset, it works if I avoid directly referring to September. Not to say that this must be a correct assertion, just a logical one.

Comment: Perhaps what I'm seeing is simply something you added to test this issue, but you are setting the `StartDate` and `EndDate` to September at the beginning of the query rather than getting them from the proc.  Take a look at that first.  Otherwise, could you provide some more details on grouping, filters, and visibility properties for the tablix?

Comment: You named your question something with "column visibility". What are the expressions for this (on the column group column and its total column)?

Comment: Steve-o169 - Good point for clarification: the declared variables in the query exist only in SSMS for debugging purposes, that portion does not exist in the report. Will add some more info on column visibility, per your and Wolfgang Kais' request.